# Get the list of all the url's of the webpages from newspaper

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to extract the list of url's or links corresponding the webpages, but when I run the below code, it just prints the urls which I gave in sabah_url_given.txt . It should actually contain "http://www.dailysabah.com/politics/2014/04/30/erdogan-no-uncertainties-ahead-of-presidential-vote
, ...." in Sabah_url_collection.txt.. Here is my Sabah_url_given.txt "http://www.dailysabah.com/search?query=Erdogan&page=1"

Here is my code:

```
from cookielib import CookieJar
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

try:
    text_file = open('sabah_url_given.txt', 'r')
    for line in text_file:
        print line
        soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(line))
        links = soup.select("ul.list")
        with open('sabah_url_collection.txt', 'a') as f:
            for link in links:
                f.write(link.get('a href') + '\n')
                url_file = open('sabah_url_collection.txt', 'r')
                for line in url_file:
                    print line
```

Comment: why are you opening the file every time in the loop?

Comment: My sabah_url_given.txt has a many number of links.say some 500 url's

Comment: what does `print links` output? Also from the link you have provided what do you want from that particular page?

Comment: Print line just prints the url's from the sabah_url_given.txt.. From the url's present in saba_usl_given.txt I want to get all the url's like "http://www.dailysabah.com/politics/2014/04/30/erdogan-no-uncertainties-ahead-of-presidential-vote, http://www.dailysabah.com/mideast/2014/07/24/pm-erdogan-israel-is-a-terror-state, etc...."These url's the webpages for a particular article..

Comment: your problem is  `links = soup.select("ul.list")` is returning nothing